# How to find and replace a string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, compare, cells

So here is my problem:

I have a list of names in Matlab in a cell array.

I automatically create directories and .mat files for each name.

My problem is that some of these names contains '/' and therefore everything go wrong when I create the directory…

So I am trying to find an efficient way to find '/' and replace them.

So far I've tried to find them using the findstr function. It then gives me a cell array with the indexes where '/' appears. So when the name doesn't contain any '/' it returns {[]} and when the function find it, it returns {[i]}.
Now i'd like to have a logical condition that says if findstr is not empty then do something. I've tried with the isempty function but it doesn't work (it's never empty…)

So does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: What would be the replacing character?

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace the character:

```
list = {'aaa', 'bb/cc', '/dd/'};
replace_from = '/'; %// character to be replaced
replace_to = '_'; %// replacing character
list_replaced = regexprep(list, replace_from, replace_to);
```

gives

```
list_replaced = 
    'aaa'    'bb_cc'    '_dd_'
```

Comment: Wonderfull! In the meantime I've found a similar function that does the job: strrep(Name_List, 'Character to be replaced', 'Replacing Character')

Comment: @MrShow Yes, `strrep` is similar. I'm less familiar with it because it only appeared in recent Matlab versions. But I think it does more or less the same, provided the sought pattern is simple